# How to create a many-to-many relationship table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm having issues creating an intermediary table to create a many-to-many relationship between 2 tables in Oracle SQL.

The three tables are:

```
doctor
patient
appointment
```

The query for the 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor
(
    Doctor_ID int,
    Doctor_FName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Doctor_LName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Department_ID int,
    Doctor_Phone_Number VARCHAR(15),
 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Doctor_ID PRIMARY KEY (Doctor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Doctor_DepartmentID 
        FOREIGN KEY (Department_ID) REFERENCES Department(Department_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Patient
(
    Patient_ID int,
    Patient_FName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Patient_LName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Patient_Address VARCHAR(50),
    Patient_Phone_Number VARCHAR(15),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Patient_ID PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT
(
    Patient_ID int,
    Doctor_ID int,
    date_Created Date,
    time_Created Time,
 
    CONSTRAINT PK_PatientDoctorID_Appointment 
        PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID, Doctor_ID, Date, Time),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PatientID_Appointment  
        FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID) REFERENCES Patient(Patient_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DoctorID_Appointment 
        FOREIGN KEY (Doctor_ID) REFERENCES Doctor(Doctor_ID)
);
```

I'm unsure as to why the `Appointment` table isn't being created. The error report generated:

> Error report
> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: Theres no data type called `Time` in Oracle. In fact `DATE` includes date and time.

Comment: Ah that's pretty bad for me to overlook, thx for the quick reply. Should I be using Date for both or probably timestamp for the time_created attribute ?

Comment: The difference between `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` is the granularity. DATE has only second precision, while TIMESTAMP has up to nanosecond precision.

Comment: Also, in the PK constraint, you should use the **column names** - not their datatype .... `PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID, Doctor_ID, date_Created, time_Created)` ...

Answer (score 1):

Two issues in the last table:

- Remove the `time_created` columns since the previous one covers the time as well.
- The first foreign key needs to include the colum `date_created`, not `date`.

With those changes, the last table should look:

```sql
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT
(
Patient_ID int,
Doctor_ID int,
date_Created Date,

CONSTRAINT PK_PatientDoctorID_Appointment
  PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID,Doctor_ID,date_Created),
CONSTRAINT FK_PatientID_Appointment FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID) 
  REFERENCES Patient(Patient_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_DoctorID_Appointment FOREIGN KEY (Doctor_ID) 
  REFERENCES Doctor(Doctor_ID)
);
```

See [running example](https://dbfiddle.uk/cMBlDsZ7).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments (Oracle `date` includes time etc), Oracle uses `varchar2` as the standard string type. (`varchar` is supported but the documentation says not to use it as it's reserved for possible future use.) Also it's more readable and reliable to define single-column constraints as part of the column definition rather than as separate clauses, and when you do this for foreign keys you can let the datatype inherit from the parent rather than repeating it.

With those points in mind, I get the following:

```
create table department
( department_id            integer constraint pk_department primary key
, department_name          varchar2(30) not null constraint uk_department_name unique
, department_phone_number  varchar2(15) constraint chk_department_phone_number check(regexp_like(department_phone_number,'^[0-9 +]+$') )
);

create table doctor
( doctor_id                integer constraint pk_doctor primary key
, doctor_fname             varchar2(30) not null
, doctor_lname             varchar2(30) not null
, department_id            constraint fk_doctor_departmentid references department(department_id)
, doctor_phone_number      varchar2(15) constraint chk_doctor_phone_number check(regexp_like(doctor_phone_number,'^[0-9 +]+$') )
);

create table patient
( patient_id               integer constraint pk_patient primary key
, patient_fname            varchar2(20) not null
, patient_lname            varchar2(20) not null
, patient_address          varchar2(50)
, patient_phone_number     varchar2(15) constraint chk_patient_phone_number check(regexp_like(patient_phone_number,'^[0-9 +]+$') )
);

create table appointment
( patient_id               constraint fk_patientid_appointment references patient (patient_id) not null
, doctor_id                constraint fk_doctorid_appointment  references doctor (doctor_id) not null
, date_created             date default on null sysdate
, appointment_date         date
, constraint pk_patientdoctorid_appointment primary key (patient_id,doctor_id,date_created)
);
```

Answer (score -4):

To create a many-to-many relationship table in Oracle SQL, you typically need three tables: two tables representing the entities involved in the relationship and a third table that serves as a junction or associative table linking the two entities. Here's an example:

Let's say we have two entities: Students and Courses, and we want to represent the many-to-many relationship between them.

Create the Students Table:

CREATE TABLE Students (
student_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
student_name VARCHAR2(100)
);

Create the Courses Table:

CREATE TABLE Courses (
course_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
course_name VARCHAR2(100)
);

Create the Junction Table:

CREATE TABLE Student_Courses (
student_id NUMBER,
course_id NUMBER,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Students(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Courses(course_id)
);

In this example, the Student_Courses table serves as the junction table that establishes the many-to-many relationship between students and courses. Each row in this table represents a combination of a student and a course they are enrolled in.

```
student_id and course_id are foreign keys referencing the student_id and course_id columns in the Students and Courses tables, respectively.
The combination of student_id and course_id is the primary key for the Student_Courses table, ensuring that each student-course combination is unique.
```

To insert data into the Student_Courses table, you would typically insert pairs of student_id and course_id values to represent the enrollment of students in courses.

Comment: I think your answer answer does not address the actual question at all, namely: why is the `CREATE TABLE` statement failing. That is probably the reason why your answer has been down-voted.